# write csv rows one by one rather than all at once in python3 using writer.writerows(reader)

Tags: python, csv, header

I am saving a csv file after skipping the rows before the header:

```
                print (latest_file)
            with open(latest_file, "r",encoding="utf8") as infile:
                reader = csv.reader(infile)
                for row in reader:
                    #look for 
                    if row[0] == 'date/time':
                        print (row)
                        break
                else:
                    print("{} not found".format('name'))
                with open("C:/s3/"+str(p.from_date)+'_'+str(p.to_date)+'_'+str(merchant["country"])+'_'+str(merchant["company"])+'_'+"payments.csv", "w", newline='') as outfile:
                    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
                    writer.writerow(row) # headers
```

I am writing the remaining rows all at once to the file:

```
                    try:
                        writer.writerows(reader) # remaining rows
                    except Exception as e:
                        print (e)
```

I would like to write the rows once by one because windows throws the following error: `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x83' in position 142: character maps to <undefined>`

It seems to be a windows issue, and since it happens so rarely, I would prefer to save the rows to the file one by one so only the problematic rows are skipped.

Comment: Your indentation looks wonky. But why can't you just do it the same way that you iterated through `reader` at the start? Just `for row in reader: writer.writerow(row)`. You can only iterate the `reader` once, so if you start reading again after the `break`, it will start from where ever it was up to already.

Comment: You used `encoding="utf8"` when opening your file for reading, but accepted the system default encoding when opening the file for writing. Your problem will likely go away once you write with the same encoding you read with.

Comment: @roganjosh believe it or not the indentation works, and yea I ended up iterating the reader like row,

Comment: @stevenRumbalski  should I write it open("C:/s3/"+str(p.from_date)+'_'+str(p.to_date)+'_'+str(merchant["country"])+'_'+str(merchant["company"])+'_'+"payments.csv", "w", encoding="utf8",newline='') ?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that worked thank you, you know I guess I dont understand the point of using this at the top of my file # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in reader:  # the same reader used for reading
    try:
        writer.writerow(row) # remaining rows
    except Exception as e:
        print(row)
        print(e)
        print()
```